Gstreamer packages libopenexr25, libflac8, libtiff5, libilmbase25 are Not Available in Ubuntu 24.04 – Suitable Replacement?
I'm setting up the Gstreamer on Ubuntu 24.04 and ran into an issue where two packages I need, libopenexr25,libflac8 and 'libtiff5', are no longer available. I received the following errors:
root@buildhost:/mnt# apt-get install libopenexr25 libflac8 libtiff5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libopenexr25
E: Unable to locate package libflac8
E: Unable to locate package libtiff5

I noticed that Ubuntu 24.04 does provide -dev packages for the same.
Ref :

https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libopenexr-dev
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libflac-dev
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libtiff5-dev

root@buildhost:/mnt# apt-get install libopenexr-dev libflac-dev libtiff5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdeflate-dev libflac12t64 libimath-3-1-29t64 libimath-dev libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblerc-dev liblzma-dev
  libogg-dev libogg0 libopenexr-3-1-30 libsharpyuv-dev libtiff-dev libtiffxx6 libwebp-dev libwebpdecoder3 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3
  libzstd-dev zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  liblzma-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdeflate-dev libflac-dev libflac12t64 libimath-3-1-29t64 libimath-dev libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblerc-dev
  liblzma-dev libogg-dev libogg0 libopenexr-3-1-30 libopenexr-dev libsharpyuv-dev libtiff-dev libtiff5-dev libtiffxx6 libwebp-dev
  libwebpdecoder3 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libzstd-dev zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4800 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

I was able to install -dev packages without issues, but I’m concerned that using the -dev versions may bring in additional headers and development libraries that might not be necessary for runtime usage.
Here are my questions:

Can I safely use -dev as replacements libopenexr25 libflac8 libtiff5 ?
Do these -dev packages include all necessary runtime functionalities, or are there alternative packages that might replace libopenexr25 libflac8 libtiff5 specifically for Ubuntu 24.04?


From your output, you can see there are libopenexr-3-1-30, libflac12t64 and libtiffxx6 being installed, which are the actual libraries. Now it's up to you decide whether those versions are suitable for your purpose
